# Crontab cannot find the function imported in my python code

Tags: python-2.7

i want to import a function from another python code.
It works when i run manually but not in crontab.

So i have this:
file1.py (the main code)
file2.py (contains a function named read())

So i tried this:

```
file1.py
import file2

url = 'api:v1/stack/alias'
params = urllib.urlencode({'local': file2.read()})
...
```

So it works when i execute it manually but not when it added in crontag.

After googling i found another solution:
fil1.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/pi')
import file2
```

It works when executed manually but still not by crontab.

So is there another way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: is file2.py in the same path? and are you sure that at least the file1.py being called from crontab?

Comment: yes all files are in the same path

Comment: yes crontab tries to execute, it fails then it sends an email and says import not found

Comment: It looks like your crontab is trying to execute the python script as a shell script. If the message you get is `import: command not found`, it's definitely getting executed by a shell. Try running your cron job as `python /path/to/file1.py`. Python gives a different error message `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named file2`. Keep it a practice to add shebang in your script. In `file1.py` put `#!/usr/bin/python` at the very top (first line).